# Wordpress Plugin to apply discount on total cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Woocommerce pulgin - 
Hi, I am looking for a wordpress plugin for my website http://fashions.aad-on.com , to apply Discount on total cart "if the total cart amount exceeds a particular amount". 
Example: 10% Discount on total cart if the total cart equals or exceeds $ 500/-

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need extra plugin for that. It is included in WooCommerce core.

Create a coupon -> Give it a code -> Select discount type as `Cart % discount` -> Set `Coupon amount` as 10 -> Set `Minimum amount` as 500 -> Save the coupon. You're done!

To apply coupon code automatically, try following code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'apply_matched_coupons' );

function apply_matched_coupons() {
    global $woocommerce;

    $coupon_code = '10percent'; // your coupon code here

    if ( $woocommerce->cart->has_discount( $coupon_code ) ) return;

    if ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total >= 500 ) {
        $woocommerce->cart->add_discount( $coupon_code );
        $woocommerce->show_messages();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried the same, but even though my cart is above $500 it was not updating automatically. 
For this discount the customer need to enter the coupon number?
what i am looking is for automatic updating the discount on the cart..
plz suggest me

Comment: No, it'll not apply the coupon automatically. To apply coupon code automatically, please refer my edited response above.

Comment: Where do you add this? In functions.php I guess right?